# MySQL optimization for insert and retrieve only

Tags: mysql, performance

Our applications read data from sensor complexes and write them to a database, together with their timestamp. New data are inserted about 5 times per second per sensor complex (1..10 complexes per database server; data contain 2 blobs of typically 25kB and 50kB, resp.), they are read from 1..3 machines (simple reads like: `select * from table where sensorId=?sensorId and timestamp>?lastTimestamp`). Rows are never updated; no reports are created on the database side; old rows are deleted after several days. Only one of the tables receives occasional updates.

The primary index of that main table is an autogenerated id, with additional indices for `sensorid` and `timestamp`.

The performance is currently abysmal. The deletion of old data takes hours(!), and many data packets are not sent to the database because the insertion process takes longer than the interval between sensor reads. How can we optimize the performance of the database in such a specific scenario?

Setting the `transaction isolation level` to `READ_COMMITTED` looks promising, and also `innodb_lock_timeout` seems useful. Can you suggest further settings useful in our specific scenario?

Can we gain further possibilities when we get rid of the table which receives updates?

Comment: Slow inserts often are caused by the database have to recreate some huge index with every insert. Please add your table and index definitions to the questions. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`.

Comment: I sense that this is more of a dba question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting old data -- `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))` lets you `DROP PARTITION` a looooot faster than doing `DELETEs`.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

And that `SELECT` you mentioned needs this 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(sensorId, timestamp)
```

Comment: I couldn't test it, but your suggestions look very reasonable (my colleagues who designed that database, now decided for a different method thinking they could get rid of the delete statement completely by some kind of updating old rows with new data...).

Comment: If you are "logically" deleting rows via a "deleted" column, you will probably need to say `AND deleted=0`" in `SELECTs`.  This _may_ have impact on performance.  We need more details to discuss further.